# Reading a file with kernel APIs when a user application is locking the same

Tags: c, windows, kernel, kmdf

I'm trying to read a database transaction log used by a DB engine. As the file is exclusively locked, I can't read it in any handles created by the user mode. Hence, I'm trying Kernel APIs such as ZwCreateFile, IoCreateFileSpecifyDeviceObjectHint, etc. The status is throwing a c0000043 error which maps to a STATUS_SHARING_VIOLATION.
Here is the code I have tried:

```
ntstatus = ZwCreateFile(&handle,
    GENERIC_READ,
    &objAttr, &ioStatusBlock,
    NULL,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    0,
    FILE_OPEN,
    FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,
    NULL, 0);
```

Any leads will help.

Comment: And so what ? Here previous mode not play role